# Problem with the definition of tree in descriptive set theory

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

I have a problem with the standard definition of **tree** in descriptive set theory.
The following is the definition:

> **Definition:** A **tree** on a set $A$ is a subset $T \subseteq A^{<\mathbb{N}}$ closed under initial segments, i.e. if $t \in T$ and $s \subseteq t$, then $s \in T$.

[Here, $A^{<\mathbb{N}}$ referes to the space of all finite sequences from $A$.]

My problem lies in particular in the next definition.

> An **infinite branch** of $T$ is a sequence $x \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x|n \in T$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

[Here, $x|n := (x_0, \dots, x_{n-1})$.]

So far, so good. I do understand the definition of infinite branch. What puzzles me is how we can have an infinite branch (that is indeed a $x \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$) in a tree $T \subseteq A^{<\mathbb{N}}$.

In other words, I don't see how is possible to make coexist an infinite object (the infinite branch) in a tree, given the very definition of tree as a subset of $A^{<\mathbb{N}}$.

As always, any feedback will be greatly welcome.
Thank you for your time and your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Branches are equivalent to *subsets* of the tree, not to elements of the tree.

A branch, essentially, is a maximal chain, which need not have a maximal element. Note that the branch is a function in $A^\Bbb N$, not in $A^{<\Bbb N}$.

The definition you quote says the following: $x\colon\Bbb N\to A$ is called an infinite branch (in $T$), if $\{x\restriction\{0,\ldots,n-1\}\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$ is a maximal chain in $T$.

On the other hand, if $C$ is an infinite maximal chain in $T$, then $\bigcup C$ is a function from $\Bbb N$ to $A$, so it is an element of $A^\Bbb N$.

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot! I am afraid I am still missing something. ***Finite*** **sequences** are elements of a tree, right?

Comment: Yes. An the branch is a function whose finite initial segments are in the tree.

Comment: Sorry. I am really struggling with this. Thus, to make everything explicit, what you are saying is that in general a branch is a function $x: \mathbb{N} \to A^{<\mathbb{N}}$ s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x|n \in T$. If this is the case, then it's fine for me. But of course, this is not the case, because we have to deal also with infinite branches, where we should have $x: \mathbb{N} \to A^{\mathbb{N}}$. Thus, do we have two definitions of **branch** _as a function_, according to the finite/infinite nature.

Comment: Why $x\colon\Bbb N\to A^\Bbb N$?

Comment: Thus (amazingly I have the feeling I am starting to get it...), the **only** definition is as a function $x: \mathbb{N} \to A^{<\mathbb{N}}$, s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x|n \in T$. And then, _exactly thanks to this condition_, we are allowed to move when we need from _finite_ to _infinite_ branches with the very same definition. Did I finally get it right?

Comment: Once again, why $x$ is a function into the tree? It's a function into $A$.

Comment: [I am really at loss, sorry!] Thus, recapitulating, you say that a **branch** is basically a sequence $x: \mathbb{N} \to A$. **If** _in addition_ $x: \mathbb{N} \to A$ s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $x|n \in T$, then we call it an **infinite branch**. Now, a tree is a $T \subseteq A^{<\mathbb{N}}$, or rephrasing $T:= \{ s \ |\ s \in A^{<\mathbb{N}} \}$. Again, I really don't see how the two definitions can coexists.

Comment: Ok, I think I see now. The point is that **nodes** are finite sequences, say $b \in T \subseteq A^{<\mathbb{N}}$, while **branches** are sequences of _coherent_ nodes, i.e $\beta \in A^{\mathbb{N}}$ s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $\beta|t \in T$!

Comment: No, a branch is a function which is the union over a maximal chain from $T$.